# JavaScript Weirdness - typeof [] === typeof {} evaluates to 'true'

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I know the strict equals in JS evaluates two things:
equality and like-typedness

Object.is() is the closest comparison I could find to gather further insight and it offered little further in my investigation.

Can anyone who groks the innards of JS better explain this? Is an array a very very strange implementation of an object? So they are empty and evaluate the same here?

I'm quite perplexed and just curious.

Comment: Uh, `typeof 0 === typeof 3`. So what?

Comment: Arrays are objects (with optimised access on integer properties and a special `.length` property)

Comment: `typeof` is simply a lookup table. See http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3 . The other piece is that everything that is not a primitive values (number, string, boolean, null, undefined) is an object.

Comment: @FelixKling Null is an object.

Comment: @JaredSmith: No it is not: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.2

Answer (score 3):

`typeof` returns the primitive type of the operand. For anything other than bools, numbers, strings, functions, and undefined, this is object.

Comment: `function` is not a type, though. `typeof` is weird

Comment: @vkurchatkin I mean, you can try it out: `typeof function() { } === "function"`

Comment: yeah, right, but it's not a type. Actual type of a function is an `object`.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are objects with a number of additional methods -- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) defines them as "high-level, list-like objects," and goes on to say:

> Arrays are list-like objects whose prototype has methods to perform
>   traversal and mutation operations.